# With lsp-ui, how can I have display warnings placed in the Echo Area

Tags: lsp-mode

With lsp-ui, how can I force the warnings to be displayed in the Echo Area?

I don't really like them as they are displayed now, on the right side of the code.

I can turn them off

```
(setq lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover nil)
(setq lsp-ui-sideline-show-diagnostics nil)
```

, but they still don't display in the Echo Area.

I had this working somehow before;)

Comment: If you don't want the sideline at all, then `lsp-ui-sideline-enable` should be set to `nil`. Whether this causes diagnostics to be showns somewhere else, I have no idea.

Comment: Maybe turn on `lsp-modeline-diagnostic-mode`?